# Blank DatabaseName column in SQL trace in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, trace, sql-server-profiler

I have run the SQL trace in SQL Server 2000. The database name column is blank even when it shows values in the database ID column.

I checked the properties of the trace, which has database name added such as:

```
Trace File Properties
   -> Data Columns
      -> Columns
         -> DatabaseName
```

in the selected data.

> EventClass DatabaseName DatbaseID HostName TextData ApplicationName
>   NTUserName LoginName CPU Reads Writes Duration ClientProcessID SPID
>   StartTime
>
> SQLTransaction **blank** 2 SERVERNAMEPRD00 execsp_executesql
>   Enterprise    Admin    DOMAIN\Admin 0 2 0 0 4092 52 2015-03-25
>   15:52:07.607

I have written `DatabaseName` as **blank** signifying that nothing is shown in the trace. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

DatabaseID 2 is the tempDb system database.

Comment: @Avi Wasn't criticizing nor looking for clarification. I gave an explanation why databasename was blank for databaseid 2. If there's a better one, pls let us know, thx.

Comment: Yes I can trace back all the databases with their IDs. It is not just one database that is included in the trace. I have plenty. But my question is  that is there a way that the database name can also be shown in the trace along side the database ID?